# Respaldo Android Studio hacia otro equipo

Tags: java, android-studio, certificado, keystore

Necesito generar un respaldo sobre `Android Studio` y sus respectivas key sha debido a que tengo app ya firmadas con esta key.

Actualmente uso `Windows 10` y este mudaria hacia un `Fedora`.

Estoy copiando la carpeta:

**`C:\Users\user_name\.android`**

La consulta es: Con este respaldo de carpeta es suficiente o que otras copias deberia generar para respaldar la firma actual.

Comment: Te refieres  que tienes aplicaciones firmadas y subidas a Google Play?

Comment: @Jorgesys exacto tengo app firmadas en playstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Necesito generar un respaldo sobre AndroidStudio y sus respectivas key
> sha debido a que tengo app ya firmadas con esta key.

**El ùnico respaldo que necesitas es el del archivo .keystore o .jks que usaste para firmar tus aplicaciones para Google Play.** Estos archivos pueden localizarse en cualquier ubicaciòn, cuando firmes tu aplicaciòn simplemente cargalos desde donde se encuentren.

No necesitas algùn otro archivo o almacen de claves  (.jks o .keystore), incluso el archivo `debug.keystore` que se encuentra dentro de

```
C:\Users\user_name\.android\
```

es generado automaticamente, incluso si lo eliminas se vuelve a generar ya que es usado para firmar las aplicaciones en "debug", por lo tanto no son necesarios ninguno de los archivos que se encuentran dentro de `C:\Users\user_name\.android\` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]